# installing Ubuntu in Virtual machine for Windows 7 host

Tags: system-installation

I have tried installing Ubuntu 16.04.6 Desktop (32 bit) in virtual machine. 
My PC is Windows 7 (64-bit, RAM - 2 GB, processor - Intel (R)Core(TM) CPU M 370 2.40 GHz).The problem is I'm unable to launch Ubuntu in my virtual machine. kindly advise whether there's any problem with the version i have used? or is there any other problem that might have occurred?
Kindly provide a solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your ram is not too big, how much RAM do you use on the Virtual Machine? While the minimum RAM for running Ubuntu is 2 GB, if it is shared with a virtual machine it might take too long when booting on a virtual machine.